# VBA Code to Add Linked Table with Primary Key

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, vba

I have an updatable view in sql server database. When I create linked table to it with ODBC, I'm asked to select unique record identifier, in order for it to be updateable.

[image: Dialog in the wizard to select unique identifier]

I need to dynamically relink this table in VBA, so I need to drop and recreate the linked table (I cannot update the TableDef.Connect property for ODBC table).

I found several solutions, which are not applicable in my case:

- create the index after linking: I cannot for ODBC source
- create the primary key in database: I cannot, it's a view

These would be applicable:

- a code which will do what the wizard does
- a code to relink without the need to delete TableDef and that works with ODBC linked table, and will not reset previously set identifier

Temporary workaround:

- convert the view to materialized view and create unique index on it

Comment: How about: http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/199482-primary-key-sql-server-linked-view-access-database ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Why can't you create an index for an ODBC source after linking?

At work, we are using Access with linked SQL Server tables, and when someone wants to connect to a different database (change from production environment to test environment), we do something like this for all tables:

```
Dim TD As TableDef
Dim ConString As String

ConString = "ODBC;DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=ServerName;DATABASE=DbName;Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

CurrentDb.TableDefs.Delete "SomeTable"

Set TD = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("SomeTable", 0, "SomeTable", ConString)
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append TD
Set TD = Nothing

CurrentDb.Execute "CREATE UNIQUE INDEX SomeIndex ON SomeTable (PrimaryKeyColumn) WITH PRIMARY"
```